# Adding Records in Association Table for many-to-many relationship without model ASP.Net MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

How to Add data in Association Table for many to many Relationship. 
For example, How can i Add data in **CoursePrograms** without creating Model of that table.

I am using **Code First from Database** approach, Visual Studio created Models for me but it has not created any model for **CourseProgram**.

I am getting related program from course and vice versa but can i add data in Association Table without Model of **CoursePrograms** ?
[image: Relation]

**Scenario :** I have Created a Program (ComputerScience) then i have Created a Course (SoftwareEngineering). Both are created individually. Now how can i Add their IDs in CoursePrograms? These are three different and Independent Tasks.

Comment: *Visual Studio created Models for me but it has not created any model for CourseProgram.*.. this is because your link table doesn't have a payload (it has no scalar property).  Maybe [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/702890/MVC-Entity-Framework-and-Many-to-Many-Relation) can help you.

Comment: @BviLLe_Kid it is not helping me bro. Can you read Edited post and help me according to scenario?

Comment: It won't create a model for you. That table is the relationship of your `ICollection<Course>` on `Program` and your `ICollection<Program>` on `Course`. There is no need for a table. When you save the relationship in your models by putting them in the respective collections, the record will automatically be created.

Comment: @krillgar thank you very much. _putting them in the respective collections_ ,These words opened my mind and i solved my problem.  
But why negative rating? it was a valid question. please i have to ask more questions in future so dont give me negative rating it bans me from asking questions.

Comment: I wasn't the one who gave you the negative rating. Never assume that of anyone. However, if I were to guess, your question showed no effort on your part. All you did was have Visual Studio create your code for you, and when you didn't see something you were expecting, it appears to us as though you just ran for the internet. One of the things you'll see a lot is the phrase "What did you try?" If you had tried to just add one on your own, you'd have seen that everything behaved as expected. THEN you could ask "Why did this work?" if you still don't get it.

Comment: @krillgar yes you are right. but i definitely tried my best to solved my problem first before posting it here but some times your mind just misses common and simplest things .. anyway thanks for your answer.... +1 for you.

Answer (score 0):

This is how i Solved my problem.

```
db.Programs.Where(p => p.Program_Id == program)
            .Select(p=>p).Single()
            .Courses.Add( course );
db.SaveChanges();
```

Where

```
program(int) = function parameter
course = object of Model 'Courses'
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider you have:

table_T1 (Id, ....)

table_T2 (Id, ....)

t1_t2    (Table_t1Id, Table_t2Id, ...) // joining table

if you want to add a new record to table_T1 and a list of new records to table_T2 and a list of (Table_t1Id, Table_t2Id)s into t1_t2:

```
table_T1 t1 = new table_T1 (); // and fill it with data
t1.table_T2 = new List<table_T2>();
t1.table_T2.Add(new t1.table_T2 {Id, ... });
t1.table_T2.Add(new t1.table_T2 {Id, ... });
dbcontext.table_T1.Add(table_T1);
dbcontext.saveChanges();
```

if you just want to add a new record to table_T1 and add a list of records t1_t2 to just point to other records already exists in table_T2:

```
table_T1 t1 = new table_T1 (); // and fill it with data
t1.table_T2 = new List<table_T2>();
t1.table_T2.Add( dbcontext.table_T2.where(Id == 1).first() );
t1.table_T2.Add( dbcontext.table_T2.where(Id == 2).first() );
dbcontext.table_T1.Add(table_T1);
dbcontext.saveChanges();
```

I figured it myself, the solution is not mentioned anywhere

Comment: you are adding model into the model? `dbcontext.table_T1.Add(table_T1);` ?

Comment: in the example, "table_T1 t1 = new table_T1 ();" is an instance of the model and is also a row of the table "table_T1" so yes I'm adding a model/row of that domain-model/table to the domain-model/table ...
it works perfect